# Char Array of Pointers storing the last line of the file for every subscript

Tags: c

so I'm writing a program that reads a mal file and it's supposed to print it to the output file. However, one of the problems I'm having is that for my first while loop, when I store the address of each line from the file to lineRef[i], inside that while loop, if I print it out immediately, it will print the correct line. However, in the 2nd while loop, it just prints the last line of the file.

```
FILE * inputFile = fopen("example.mal", "r");
FILE * outputFile = fopen("output.lst", "w");

char linesFromFile[256];
char * lineRef[50];
char * labels[50];

int i = 0;
while(fgets(linesFromFile, 256, inputFile) != NULL)
{
    lineRef[i] = linesFromFile;
    i++;
}

i = 0;
while(lineRef[i] != NULL)
{
    printf("%s\n", lineRef[i]);
    i++;
}
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lineRef[i] = linesFromFile;
```

Here you are assigning same address of `linesFromFile` to all elements of `lineRef`
You need to allocate memory for each line read into each element of `lineRef` then copy contents of linesFromFile into it.

e.g

```
while(fgets(linesFromFile, 256, inputFile) != NULL)
{
    lineRef[i] = malloc(256);
    memset(lineRef[i],'\0',256);
    strncpy(lineRef[i] , linesFromFile,256);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Sorry what did you mean by allocate memory for each line? I know how to allocate memory but I'm not sure how to allocate it for each line.

Comment: `char * lineRef[50];` creates an *array of pointers to char [50 of them]*. The pointers are *uninitialized* and do not point anywhere. In order to have them point somewhere meaningful (where you can store a line), you need to allocated a block of memory and assign the starting address for that block to one of the pointers. You then copy the line to that block of memory. You do that for each line. (you then need to `free` each block when you are done with it)